# How can I replace HTML content using XSLT?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I would like to remove a certain text from an HTML page using XSLT. The text I would like to remove is `<h2>OLD TEXT</h2>`. I'm trying to remove it by replacing the text with an empty string but I don't get it to work.

When calling my string-replace-all function with "`<h2>OLD TEXT</h2>`" text as input I get the following error:

```
The value of the attribute "select" associated with an element type "xsl:with-param" must not contain the '<' character.
```

When calling my string-replace-all function with just "OLD TEXT" as input the text gets replaced but the output
is no longer HTML, it's just plain text without the HTML tags.

How could I do to replace `<h2>OLD TEXT</h2>` and still get the output in HTML format?

My code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">


   <xsl:output method="html" />

   <xsl:template name="string-replace-all">
       <xsl:param name="text" />
       <xsl:param name="replace" />
       <xsl:param name="by" />
       <xsl:choose>
           <xsl:when test="$text = '' or $replace = ''or not($replace)" >
               <!-- Prevent this routine from hanging -->
               <xsl:copy-of select="$text" />
           </xsl:when>
           <xsl:when test="contains($text, $replace)">
               <xsl:copy-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)" />
               <xsl:copy-of select="$by" />
               <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
                   <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$replace)" />
                   <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace" />
                   <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by" />
               </xsl:call-template>
           </xsl:when>
           <xsl:otherwise>
               <xsl:copy-of select="$text" />
           </xsl:otherwise>
       </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:variable name="updatedHtml">
    <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
      <xsl:with-param name="text" select="//div[@id='mainContent']" />
      <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'OLD TEXT'" />
      <xsl:with-param name="by" select="''" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:variable>  


    <xsl:template match="//div[@id='mainContent']">         
        <xsl:copy-of select="$updatedHtml" />
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Test page</title>
</head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="mainContent">
        <h1>Header one</h1> 
        <p>Some text</p>
        <h2>OLD TEXT</h2> 
        <p>Some information about the old text</p>
        <br>
        More text
        <h2>Another header</h2>           
        Some information <strong>with strong</strong> text.
        <h2>Another header again</h2>           
        Some information <strong>with strong</strong> text.       
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show minimal but complete samples to allow us to reproduce the problem, how does a minimal XML input sample look, which result do you want? Or do you run XSLT against a non XML HTML document? Then please include details of how exactly you do that.

Comment: With the given information, it seems you can remove `<h2>OLD TEXT</h2>` by simply using `<xsl:template match="h2[. = 'OLD TEXT']"/>` . You don't need to use `<xsl:template name="string-replace-all">`

Comment: I've added the HTML input.

Comment: Thanks @Vebbie! I tried your solution and it did remove the OLD TEXT header but the output is just plain text, not HTML.

Comment: Try adding `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` in your stylesheet.

Comment: The stylesheet you show us has no `<` character in `select` atribute of `xsl:with-param` instruction, wich it's the reported error.